# TensorFlow dynamic_rnn regressor: ValueError dimension mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to build a toy LSTM model for regression. [This](http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html) nice tutorial is already too complicated for a beginner.

Given a sequence of length `time_steps`, predict the next value. Consider `time_steps=3` and the sequences:

```
array([
   [[  1.],
    [  2.],
    [  3.]],

   [[  2.],
    [  3.],
    [  4.]],
    ...
```

the target values should be:

```
array([  4.,   5., ...
```

I define the following model:

```
# Network Parameters
time_steps = 3 
num_neurons= 64 #(arbitrary)
n_features = 1

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, time_steps, n_features])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])

# Define weights
weights = {
   'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, 1]))
} 
biases = {
   'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}

#LSTM model
def lstm_model(X, weights, biases, learning_rate=0.01, optimizer='Adagrad'):

  # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
  # Current data input shape: (batch_size, time_steps, n_features)
  # Required shape: 'time_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_features)
  # Permuting batch_size and time_steps
  input dimension: Tensor("Placeholder_:0", shape=(?, 3, 1), dtype=float32)

  X = tf.transpose(X, [1, 0, 2])
  transposed dimension: Tensor("transpose_41:0", shape=(3, ?, 1), dtype=float32)

  # Reshaping to (time_steps*batch_size, n_features)
  X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_features])
  reshaped dimension: Tensor("Reshape_:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

  # Split to get a list of 'time_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_features)
  X = tf.split(0, time_steps, X)
  splitted dimension: [<tf.Tensor 'split_:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split_:1' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split_:2' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]

  # LSTM cell
  cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_neurons) #Or GRUCell(num_neurons)

  output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float32)

  output = tf.transpose(output, [1, 0, 2])
  last = tf.gather(output, int(output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)


  return tf.matmul(last, weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

We instantiating the LSTM model with `pred = lstm_model(x, weights, biases)` I get the following:

```
---> output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float32)
ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 for 'transpose_42' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,1], [3]
```

1) Do you know what the problem is?

2) Will multiplying the LSTM output by the weights yield the regression?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace for the error? From the error message, it appears that some `tf.transpose()` op is being applied to a 2-D tensor, but the dimension permutation (second argument) has three values. I'd guess it comes from [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dc7293fe0f8084af1f608a5f0d4e93acd9f597f6/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L488), and the problem is that `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()` expects all the timesteps to be packed together in a single tensor. Try removing the `tf.split()` and passing the original `X` value to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`.

Comment: @mrry I believe that the input dimension for dynamic_rdd() should be (batch_size, time_steps, n_features). Therefore there should be no need for the 'pre-processing' steps I do there

Comment: Right. I think this is a poor error message. You're passing a list of `time_steps` 2-D tensors but the correct input would be a single 3-D tensor (and the first dimension should be `batch_size` rather than `time_steps`, so the transpose shouldn't be necessary either).

Comment: @mrry Indeed that works. output dimension is (?, 3, 1)  which I believe should be (batch_size, time_steps, n_features). Would it make sense to do tf.matmul(output, weights['out']) and compare this to the target for the regression part?

Comment: I think you'd probably slice out the last time step from the output (e.g. `output[:, -1, :]`, and use that as the input to the final layer (`weights['out']` and `biases['out']`) and compare that to the target value.

Comment: @mrry in this case weights['out'] is just a scalar though, am I correct?

Comment: I was assuming it would be an `n_output` x `target_features` matrix, which I suppose would be a 1x1 matrix and equivalent to `tf.multiply()`-ing by a scalar, yes.

Comment: @mrry probably not the best prediction, but finally something working [image](http://i64.tinypic.com/16c8bpe.png)

Comment: @mrry I was surprised to see that indexing works nicely on the tensor: output[:,-1, :]. Has this feature been implemented? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206

Comment: Yes, that feature's been in since TensorFlow 0.11, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, ...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) function expects a list of three-dimensional tensors<sup>*</sup> as its `inputs` argument, where the dimensions are interpreted by default as `batch_size` x `num_timesteps` x `num_features`. (If you pass `time_major=True`, they are interpreted as `num_timesteps` x `batch_size` x `num_features`.) Therefore the preprocessing you've done in the original placeholder is unnecessary, and you can pass the oriding `X` value directly to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically it can accept complicated nested structures in addition to lists, but the leaf elements must be three-dimensional tensors.<sup>**</sup>

<sup>**</sup> Investigating this turned up a bug in the implementation of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`. In principle, it should be sufficient for the inputs to have at least two dimensions, but the `time_major=False` path assumes that they have exactly three dimensions when it transposes the input into the time-major form, and it was the error message that this bug inadvertently causes that showed up in your program. We're working on getting that fixed.

Comment: If I don't do the preprocessing on X and pass it directly then it is throwing the error :
ValueError: None values not supported.
@  outputs, _, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell_m, lstm_bw_cell_m, x, dtype=tf.float32)