# ValueError: ConvLSTMCell and dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a seq2seq model in tensorflow (1.4) using the tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell API together with the tf.nn.dynamic_rnn API, but I got an error with the dimension of the inputs.

My code is:

```
# features is an image sequence with shape [600, 400, 10], 
# so features is a tensor with shape [batch_size, 600, 400, 10]

features = tf.transpose(features, [0,3,1,2])
features = tf.reshape(features, [params['batch_size'],10,600,400])   

encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(conv_ndims=2,
                                           input_shape=[600, 400,1],
                                           output_channels=5,
                                           kernel_shape=[7,7],
                                           skip_connection=False)

_, encoder_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=encoder_cell,
                                     inputs=features,
                                     sequence_length=[10]*params['batch_size'],
                                     dtype=tf.float32)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Conv Linear expects all args to be of same Dimension: [[2, 600, 400], [2, 600, 400, 5]]
```

Looking at the tf implementation, it seems that the inputs to dynamic_rnn is only 3-dimensional in contrary to the hidden state, which is 4-dimensional. I tried to pass the input as a nested tuple, but it didn't work.

The problem is similar to [TensorFlow dynamic_rnn regressor: ValueError dimension mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513613/tensorflow-dynamic-rnn-regressor-valueerror-dimension-mismatch), it's slightly different though, as they're using a plain LSTMCell (which worked for me).

Can anyone give me a minimal example how to use these 2 APIs together? 
Thanks!

Comment: your `input_shape` is `[600, 400, 1]` and then your `inputs=features` has shape `batch_size, 10, 600, 400` even though it should be: `batch_size, 10, 600, 400,1`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from here https://github.com/iwyoo/ConvLSTMCell-tensorflow/issues/2
Currently, **tf.nn.dynamic_rnn** doesn't support **ConvLSTMCell**.

Therefore, as described here, https://github.com/iwyoo/ConvLSTMCell-tensorflow/issues/1 you have to manually create the **RNN**.

An example is provided in the documentation, https://github.com/iwyoo/ConvLSTMCell-tensorflow/blob/master/README.md

Below I have modified your code according to the above example with the comments where necessary.

```
height = 400
width = 400
time_steps = 25
channel = 10
batch_size = 2

p_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, time_steps, channel])
p_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, 3])

p_input_list = tf.split(p_input, step_size, 3) # creates a list of leghth time_steps and one elemnt has the shape of (?, 400, 400, 1, 10)
p_input_list = [tf.squeeze(p_input_, [3]) for p_input_ in p_input_list] #remove the third dimention now one list elemnt has the shape of (?, 400, 400, 10)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.ConvLSTMCell(conv_ndims=2, # ConvLSTMCell definition
                                   input_shape=[height, width, channel],
                                   output_channels=5,
                                   kernel_shape=[7, 7],
                                   skip_connection=False)

state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32) #initial state is zero

with tf.variable_scope("ConvLSTM") as scope:  # as BasicLSTMCell # create the RNN with a loop
    for i, p_input_ in enumerate(p_input_list):
        if i > 0:
            scope.reuse_variables()
        # ConvCell takes Tensor with size [batch_size, height, width, channel].
        t_output, state = cell(p_input_, state)
```

Notice that you have to input an image that has the same **height** and **width**. If your **height** and **width** doesn't match, then you may have to do padding.

hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer!

If **tf.nn.dynamic_rnn** doesn't support **ConvLSTMCell** it explains why my code is not working. Can anyone confirm this?
Because for me it looks like iwyoo created his own convlstm cell, which is not working with tensorflow ops. But what about the official tensorflow implementation of ConvLSTMCell [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/ConvLSTMCell]. Or is this the implementation tf adopted (it looks very similar at least)?

And why do I need height and width be equal? I don't get that

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I figured out how to use the 2 APIs together. The trick is to pass a 5D-Tensor as input to tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(), where the last dimension is the size of the "vector on the spatial grid" (which comes from the transformation of the input from 2D to 3D, inspired by the paper on which the implementation is based: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04214.pdf). In my case the vector size is 1, I have to expand the dimension anyway though.

While fixing this error another issue emerged: In the paper mentioned above in section 3.1 they state the equations for the convLSTM. They use the Hadamard-product for weights connected to the cell outputs C. Printing the weights of my ConvLSTMCell in Tensorflow, it seems like they don't use the weights Wci, Wcf and Wco at all. So, can anybody tell me the exact implementation of the TF ConvLSTMCell?

Btw. the output of the tensorflow ConvSTMCell is C or H (in the notation of the paper)?